# Azure Worker Role What went wrong before OnRun() method?

Tags: c#, azure

I have suddenly started getting key not found error in my worker role.

> Configuration is missing required information. Make sure the property
>   'Endpoint' is defined as part of
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString' key within 'appSettings'
>   section, or Windows Azure configuration settings.

What I have tried:

Setting name `Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString` is present in Cloud config.

> ```
> <Role name="MyWorkerRole">
> <ConfigurationSettings>
>   <Setting name="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://mysevicebus.servicebus.windows.net />
> ```

Service definition file.

```
<ConfigurationSettings>   <Setting name="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" />
```

Package.Config entry for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager` points to correct version 2.0.3

App.Config: Runtime -> AssemblyBinding -> DependentAssembly for `AzureServiceRuntime`, `ServiceBus` & `AzureConfiguration` packages are correct.

Not sure what else to look into. Can you please help?

P.S. The exception is thrown after `OnStart()` method, just before hitting Run() method.

Comment: Did you try run locally? Put a try / catch on your OnStart() method and log it in a Sql Database for example.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Yes I got this error in local only. I obtained this exception after putting the code in try catch block.

Comment: As you got this exception locally, you can debug it, right? It seems to be a object that you're trying to instatiate. Probably your "ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg" file and "ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg" are different. Maybe you're missing the ConfigurationSettings in your "ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg" file

Comment: Other than the try catch block, I was able to get it via Debug -> Exceptions -> Check "Thrown" on CLR Exceptions. This will tell the debugger to pause as if it were a catch block when something is unhandled. I have found this to be incredibly useful for preemptively resolving issues in my code base. i.e. Errors that are occurring, not breaking the application, but nobody is seeing them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to add the SharedAccessKey and RootManagedSharedAccessKey? They are missing from you application's code demonstrated above. I have this in the app settings of my Role as well as the service configuration.

```
<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://yourSBname.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=KeyFromPortal" />
```